# Variável passada para view não contém o valor definido

Tags: php, mvc

Estou criando um framework PHP e na minha classe do Controlador, eu tenho um método `render`, aonde eu recebo dois parâmetros, o nome do arquivo (que seria a view), e um array das variáveis que serão passadas para essa view.

```
function render($arquivo, $variaveis = [])
{
    extract($variaveis); // extrai as variáveis que serão passadas para a view

    require $arquivo;
}
```

Essas variáveis serão passadas para a view dessa forma:

```
$variavel1 = 'teste1';
$variavel2 = 'teste2';

$this->render('minha-view.php', compact('variavel1', 'variavel2'));
```

### O problema

Se eu tiver uma variável `$arquivo` no meu controlador, e o valor dessa variável é uma string qualquer, o valor que é passado para a minha view seria o primeiro parâmetro que foi passado para o método `render`. Exemplo:

meucontrolador.php

```
$arquivo = 'arquivo.xyz.txt';

// passa a variável $arquivo para a view minha-view.php
$this->render('minha-view.php', compact('arquivo'));
```

minha-view.php

```
<body>
    <?php echo $arquivo; ?> <!-- ao invés de imprimir 'arquivo.xyz.txt' ele imprime 'minha-view.php' -->
</body>
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Não utilize a funcção compact() utilize a função extract() ela já prevê esse problema e permite você definir um prefixo nesses casos onde existe variáveis com o mesmo nome, pois o php sempre irá priorizar a variável criada primeiro.

Isso resolve seu problema, mas você terá de utilizar uma única variável e centralizar seus dados para extração em um array, o que também irá te poupar esforço pois você não terá de ficar ditando cada variável que você criou para ser extraída, a função irá percorrer o array e cuidar do resto.

No caso para criar uma variável $arquivo você irá fazer da seguinte forma.

```
// Cria um array vazio
$data = [];    

// Cria uma chave contendo o nome do arquivo
$data['arquivo'] = 'arquivo.xyz.txt';

// Passa o array para extração e define um prefixo caso já exista uma variavel com mesmo nome
extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "prefixo");
```

Quando você for imprimir o valor terá uma variável criada com o mesmo nome da chave do array

```
echo $arquivo;
```

Ou

Caso exista uma variável de mesmo já criada antes da extração

```
echo $prefixo_arquivo;
```

Espero ter ajudado!